# Checkbox button is not located inline with the other buttons

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm using `Vue` and `vue-strap`. I have the following code:

```
<div slot="modal-header" class="modal-header">  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default action_btn" v-on:click="closed">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        Close
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info action_btn" v-on:click="calData">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
        refresh
    </button>
    <dropdown type="info">
        <button slot="before" type="button" class="btn btn-info" v-on:click="calData">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
            Export
        </button>
         <li v-for="current_box in checkboxes">
            <checkbox :checked.sync="current_box.value" v-model="current_box.value">{{current_box.name}}</checkbox>
        </li>
    </dropdown>
</div>
```

But it looks like:

[image]

The `export` button is not nearby the `refresh` button.
The css:

```
modal-header {
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

I have tried all possible displays but without any success. How should I debug it?

Comment: I think the refresh and close button is `float: right` and the export is `float: left`.

Comment: Open the developer tools and inspect the CSS styles being applied to the elements. The first step is to establish which CSS rules are causing the difference. Once you know that you can work back to figure out why those rules are being applied.

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproduction of this issue in codepen?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modal-header {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-header">
  <button class="btn">close</button>
  <button class="btn">refresh</button>
  <dropdown style="float:left;">
    <button class="btn">export</button>
  </dropdown>
</div>

<div class="modal-header">
  <button class="btn">close</button>
  <button class="btn">refresh</button>
  <dropdown style="float:right;">
    <button class="btn">export</button>
  </dropdown>
</div>
```

I guess your situation is like this.